# Apple mail signature with picture on the left and text on the right

Tags: mail.app

I am trying to setup a signature with a logo on the left side, and the signature text on the right side.

I've tried all the following possibilities:

- Create the layout from Word, and paste it in Mac Mail
- Create a custom HTML file, and paste it in Mac Mail

Although it originally displays it properly, the moment that I close and re-open the window, the layout gets destroyed, which tells it was never properly saved. I've tried it more than 100 times.

I've included two screenshots with a before and after.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Would anybody know how to have the logo on the left and the text on the right, without resorting to putting it as an image which cannot be copy pasted.